# CSS last-child selector not working

Tags: html, css, less, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply styles to the last `<p>` in a div. I'd like to do so without adding a new class (or ID).

I've tried using the last-child selector but it's not working.

I have even tried declaring `p:last-child {font-style: italic;}` for all of my CSS document and this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="new-section">
  <div class="collection-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="title span16">
          <h1>The Title</h1>
        </div>          
        <div class="span8">
          <p>Some text.</p>
          <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
          <p>Visit now</p>
          <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my LESS CSS:

```
.collection-container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: @gray;
  .container {
    padding-top: @r-margin;
    .title {
      margin-bottom: @xs-margin;
    }
    .span8 p:last-child {
      font-style: italic;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing a dot in front of span8

Comment: Is the missing dot on the `span8` class really missing in your code?

Comment: The dot was actually in my code, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a working example after I have removed the redundant code to show you how it works http://jsfiddle.net/RDpcM/1/

It's **always** a good idea to format your code and try to break out the bits that matter when trying to debug. It's very easy to get a closing bracket wrong and it all goes pear shaped.

```
<div class="span8">

    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
    <p>Visit now</p>

</div>

div p:last-child    {
     font-style: italic;
    border:solid 1px blue;

 }
​
```

**[EDIT - using JQuery]**

If you have other elements in div.span8 and don't know the number of elements up front you can introduce some jquery to achieve the desired affect.

Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPbv2/

or this will work as a standalone example for you to try out. JQuery dynamically sets the `mySelected` class when the document loads.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.mySelected  {
    font-style: italic;
    border:solid 1px blue;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.span8 > p:last").addClass("mySelected");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="span8">
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
        <p>Visit now</p>
        <div>xxx</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[EDIT - non JQuery]**

You pointed out that the original answer will not work when you have this code

```
<div class="span8">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
    <p>Visit now</p>

    <div> another non-P tag that will mess up the p:last-child selector</div>

</div>
```

So you have to make sure you don't have any other siblings for your `<p>` tags by wrapping them in an extra div like this

```
<div class="span8">
    <div class="only-for-p">
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
        <p>Visit now</p>
    </div>

    <div> this non-P tag no longer messes with the p:last-child selector</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey there, so this doesn't exactly solve the problem but it was very helpful. In my example, the last child is actually a `div`. In your (correct) jsfiddle, the `div` is removed and the code works. However, I want that `div` there, which means `last-child` may not be the appropriate solution. Is there a way to say, "target the last p" as opposed to "target the last-child if it is a p"?

Comment: It's getting a bit hacky now, but [this will work in CSS3](http://jsfiddle.net/vgBLR/) if you know there is only *one" additional child element so you can count backwards using `p:nth-last-child(2)`

Comment: If you need a CSS2 solution can you just add another `<div>` to wrap the `<p>` tags so you know there wont be another child to mess it up. Its another level of nesting but it shouldn't harm your layout with margins and padding removed

Comment: Clever idea to wrap the `p`s in a `div`. So obvious in retrospect. In the slightly hacky example is it where n is the number represented in the argument in brackets?

Comment: In both cases, these suggestions work. Fantastic! Thank you for sticking with me. Does it make sense to add those additional suggestions to your answer above, then I mark it as correct?

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with a JQuery solution and the CCS2 solution you said works for you.

Comment: Awesome! Answered! If I could upvote it more than once, I would. Thank you again.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like this would be an appropriate place to use `:last-of-type`, to select the last `p` in its parent element:

```
.span8 p:last-of-type {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/hubfiddle/TVYnA/)

Answer (score 4):

I think your syntax is wrong. Should be...

```
.span8   p:last-child {font-style: italic;}
```

You are missing the period..

Also if you aren't concerned about using CSS3 you could do...

```
.span8   p:nth-child(3) { }
```

This is useful for getting those middle elements.

Comment: @Olly see my answer with a link to JSFiddle so you can see it working

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you need to use either **p:last** or **p:last-of-type** selector, because last child of div.span8 is div.arrow-right and not p

Answer (score 0):

```
div.span8 p:last-child { font-style:italic; }
```

Answer (score 0):

your css is not working as p tag is not the last child of span8.
if you change
`.span8 p:last-child {font-style: italic;}`
to
`.span8 p:nth-last-child(2) {font-style: italic;}` it will work